Ng serviceworker not registering after making ngx-indexed-db work
I have installed ngx-indexed-DB to make the app work when offline after installing ng service worker but the problem is after making the indexed DB work the ng service worker is not registering.
my ngsw.config.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": [
        "**/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 25,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "timeout": "10s"
      }
    }

  ]

}

my main.ts code:
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => {
    if (environment.production) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
      console.log('wwwwwwwwwwwoooooooooooooooo');
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

my DBService code:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DbserviceService {

  constructor(
    private dbService: NgxIndexedDBService,

  ) { }

  add(key: string, data): Observable<any> {

    return this.dbService.add(key, { data })
  }
  update(key: string, id: number, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.update(key, { id, data });
  }
  getById(key: string, id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.getByID<any>(key, id);
  }
  getAll(key: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.getAll<any>(key);
  }
  delete(key: string, id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.delete(key, id);
  }
  deleteDB(key: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.deleteDatabase();
  }
  deleteAll(key: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.deleteObjectStore(key)
  }

  // getByKey(key: string, arr: any): Observable<any> {
  //   return this.dbService.bulkGet(key, arr)
  // }
  bulkadd(key: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.dbService.bulkAdd(key, data);
  }
}

my app.module.ts:
export function migrationFactory() {
  // The animal table was added with version 2 but none of the existing tables or data needed
  // to be modified so a migrator for that version is not included.
  return {
    1: (db, transaction) => {
      const store = transaction.objectStore('dashboardEnergyConsumption');
      store.createIndex('data1', 'data1', { unique: false });
    },
    3: (db, transaction) => {
      const store = transaction.objectStore('people');
      store.createIndex('data', 'data', { unique: false });

    }
  };
}

const dbConfig: DBConfig = {
  name: 'MyDb',
  version: 3,
  objectStoresMeta: [{
    store: 'dashboardEnergyConsumption',
    storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
    storeSchema: [
      { name: 'dashboardEnergyData', keypath: 'dashboardEnergyData', options: { unique: false } }
     
    ]
  },
  {
    store: 'people',
    storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
    storeSchema: [
      { name: 'data', keypath: 'data', options: { unique: false } }
    ]
  },

  ],
  // provide the migration factory to the DBConfig
  migrationFactory
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RrLeftMenuModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      preventDuplicates: true,
      positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"
    }),

    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts: () => import('echarts'),
    }),
    HeaderModule, SidePanelModule, CardModule, IconModule,
    GoogleMapsModule,
    JoyrideModule.forRoot(),
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' //'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }),
    NgxIndexedDBModule.forRoot(dbConfig),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, DatePipe, AuthService, HttpService, AppService, DmatService, RrHomeService,
    EnterpriseService, CacheInterceptor,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: load, deps: [HttpService, DomainService], multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CacheInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(iconService: IconService) {
    iconService.registerIconObject(Icons);
  }
}

can anybody tell me what is wrong and give me a solution for this problem, it would be really helpful.

The answer was simple all i had to do was introduce serviceworker: true in angular.json under production
my angular json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
      "dm-portal": {
          "projectType": "application",
          "schematics": {},
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "prefix": "app",
          "architect": {
              "build": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                  "options": {
                      "outputPath": "dist/dm",
                      "index": "src/index.html",
                      "main": "src/main.ts",
                      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                      "aot": false,
                      "assets": [
                        "src/favicon.ico",
                        "src/assets",
                        "src/manifest.webmanifest"
                      ],
                      "styles": [
                          "src/styles.css",
                          "src/styles.scss",
                          "src/font.scss",
                          "src/assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
                      ],
                      "scripts": [],
                      "vendorChunk": true,
                      "extractLicenses": false,
                      "buildOptimizer": false,
                      "sourceMap": true,
                      "optimization": true,
                      "namedChunks": true,
                      "serviceWorker": true,
                      "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                      "production": {
                        "serviceWorker": true, // <<====== Add this 
                          "fileReplacements": [{
                              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                          }],
                          "optimization": true,
                          "outputHashing": "all",
                          "sourceMap": false,
                          "namedChunks": false,
                          "extractLicenses": true,
                          "vendorChunk": false,
                          "budgets": [{
                                  "type": "initial",
                                  "maximumWarning": "8mb",
                                  "maximumError": "12mb"
                              },
                              {
                                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                  "maximumWarning": "60kb",
                                  "maximumError": "100kb"
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  }
              },
              "serve": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                  "options": {
                      "browserTarget": "dm-portal:build"
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                      "production": {
                          "browserTarget": "dm-portal:build:production"
                      }
                  }
              },
              "extract-i18n": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                  "options": {
                      "browserTarget": "dm-portal:build"
                  }
              },

              "lint": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                  "options": {
                      "tsConfig": [
                          "tsconfig.app.json",
                          "tsconfig.spec.json",
                          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                      ],
                      "exclude": [
                          "**/node_modules/**"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              "e2e": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                  "options": {
                      "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                      "devServerTarget": "dm-portal:serve"
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                      "production": {
                          "devServerTarget": "dm-portal:serve:production"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "cli": {
      "analytics": "024a4c04-d029-413a-8952-ea25a44ec446"
  }
}

